# Does compound assignment of two unsigned integers of the same type always operate as if using that type's modular arithmetic?

Tags: c++, unsigned-integer, modular-arithmetic

Here is a conjecture:

For expression `a op b` where `a` and `b` are of the same unsigned integral type `U`, and `op` is one of the compound assignment operators (`+=`,`-=`,`*=`,`/=`,`%=`,`&=`,`|=`,`^=`,`<<=`,`>>=`), the result is computed directly in the value domain of `U` using modular arithmetic, as if no *integral promotions* or *usual arithmetic conversions*, etc. are performed at all.

Is this true? What about signed integral types?

To clarify: By definition *integral promotions* and *usual arithmetic conversions* do apply here. I'm asking if the result is the same as not applying them.

I'm looking for an answer in C++, but if you can point out the difference with C, it would also be nice.

Comment: If you have `int a, b` and then do `a = static_cast<int>(static_cast<long>(a) op static_cast<long>(b));` you should be able to compare that to `a op b;` to see if there's a difference.

Comment: "... are of the same unsigned type `unsigned`, `unsigned long`, `unsigned long long`, ..." is more clear than the fuzzy _type_ `U`.  Suggest edit.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Counter example:

`int` has width `31` plus one bit for sign, `unsigned short` has width `16`. With `a` and `b` of type `unsigned short`, after integral promotions, the operation is performed in `int`.

If `a` and `b` have value `2^16 - 1`, then the mathematical exact result of `a * b` in the natural numbers would be `2^32 - 2^17 + 1`. This is larger than `2^31 - 1` and therefore cannot be represented by `int`.

Arithmetic overflow in signed integral types results in undefined behavior. Therefore `a *= b` has undefined behavior. It would not have this undefined behavior if unsigned arithmetic modulo `2^width(unsigned short)` was used.

(Applies to all C and C++ versions.)

Comment: I believe this example is the only example. An unsigned type of half the size of int gives UB for `a * b`. Anything smaller and the result of any op fits, anything bigger and it doesn't get promoted to `int`.

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow I think before C++20 you can also produce mismatching results if e.g. one's complement is used via the bitwise operators. Also, technically you can have e.g. a `unsigned short` of width `15`. Not all bits of `short` are required to participate in the value representation. Some may be padding. Then there would still be promotion to `int` and then you can even get `+` to overflow. Not sure if that covers everything. I could have missed some cases.

Comment: Never heard of any system where the types are not twice as wide as the next smaller type. Although I do want to have an uint96_t.